# How to nest if statements correctly? NameError after the second if statement

Tags: python, conditional-statements

The second nested if statement doesn't recognise declared name. I have commented out the code after the second if statement, but that have I need it. There are many rows in the file. From those that have CDS string in them I need a sign, `row[6]`, whereas those that have feature string in them I need everything, but I also need to know the sign. The ID's in both CDS and feature rows should match, hence the test `if t.group(2) == n.group(2)`. I tried continue statement, but it's still not working. Thanks for help guys

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../scripts/gff_cds.py", line 22, in <module>
    print sign
NameError: name 'sign' is not defined

import sys, csv, re

gff_ref = open(sys.argv[1])
parse_ref = csv.reader(gff_ref, delimiter='\t')

writer = csv.writer(sys.stdout)

ref_list = [] 

for row in parse_ref:
    if len(row) > 1 and 'remark' not in row and 'CDS' in row:
        t = re.search('(Transcript):(\w+.\w+\.?[0-9]?)', row[8])
        temp = t.group(2)
        sign = row[6]
    #    continue
    if 'feature' in row:
        print sign, temp
    #    ref_dict = {}
    #    n = re.search('(\W\w+):(\w+.\w+\.?[0-9]?)', row[8])
    #    if temp == n.group(2):
    #        ref_dict['seqname'] = row[0]; ref_dict['start'] = int(row[3]);
    #        ref_dict['end'] = int(row[4]); ref_dict['strand'] = sign;
    #        ref_dict['id'] = t.group(2)
    #        
    #        ref_list.append(ref_dict)
```

E.g

CHROMOSOME_I feature inferred_parent 13349410 13358674 . . . ID=Transcript:Y40B1A.3c

CHROMOSOME_I Coding_transcript CDS 13349410 13349478 . + 0 ID=CDS:Y40B1A.3c;Parent=Transcript:Y40B1A.3c;status=Partially_confirmed;wormpep=CE:CE45409

CHROMOSOME_I Coding_transcript CDS 13353007 13353245 . + 0       ID=CDS:Y40B1A.3c;Parent=Transcript:Y40B1A.3c;status=Partially_confirmed;wormpep=CE:CE45409

CHROMOSOME_I Coding_transcript CDS 13354069 13354225 . + 0       ID=CDS:Y40B1A.3c;Parent=Transcript:Y40B1A.3c;status=Partially_confirmed;wormpep=CE:CE45409

Comment: What's up with the `if t is None: print None`? Why would you want to print `None`? That `print` won't ever run, anyway, since the `t.group(2)` would raise an `AttributeError` first.

Comment: My regular expression wasn't working initially. I have put that test in to see if everything was working. I've edited it out now.

Answer (score 2):

You only assign `sign` if the `len(row) > 1 and 'remark' not in row and 'CDS' in row` check gives a true result. If it's false, `sign` never receives a value, but you attempt to use it anyway.

I don't understand what you're trying to do with this code, so I can't determine the correct fix, but a good first thing to do would be to check your indentation levels. Make sure things that should be in an `if` block are in the block, and things that shouldn't be in the block are unindented.

Comment: I was guessing that `sign` belongs to that if statement, but how do I make it accessible by the second if statement??

Comment: @Serine: That depends on the semantics of your program. Maybe the second `if` block belongs inside the first. Maybe `sign` should be assigned unconditionally. Maybe you'll need a deeper change. I don't know what you're actually trying to do, or what your CSV looks like, and I can't figure that out from your code, partly because your code isn't a complete description of the problem and partly because your code is wrong.

Comment: You see how first row has _feature_ in it, but no sign in `row[6]`, whereas the line below it belongs to the same gene (because id's are the same) and it has the `+` sign. I need that `+` sign in my first row